# i18next works on dev server but not in azure app-service

Tags: reactjs, azure, i18next

I have made a react application, using the i18next package to translate it. 
Because I have installed the i18n-backend module, I have located my files in the directory "public/locales/en/translation.json".
While I'm developing, this works just fine. But if I deploy it to an AZURE App-Service it gives me the warning "missing keys".

Just to mention:

> The files do exist in the directory from the App-Service and it's the
>   same path.

But I cannot acces them via the URL

"myApplicationURL/locales/en/translation.json".
[image]

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const fallbackLng = ['en'];
const availableLanguages = ['en', 'de'];

i18n
    .use(Backend)

    .use(LanguageDetector)

    .use(initReactI18next)

    .init({
        fallbackLng,
        debug: true,
        whitelist: availableLanguages,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        },
    });

export default i18n;
```

Has anyone ever had this problem? 
If I'm honest, I have no approach how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: its very clear that the translation json is missing in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. If you have the same problem just insert:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

into the web.config file.
This allows the server to serve the json files.

Answer (score 1):

Running locally react (webpack) serves your local /public folder with the devserver -> on your server this magic does not exist...the files just do not be served by the server without configuration...